# how to launch jenkins with previous jobs

Tags: jenkins

I shutdown jenkins for some purpose. Wonted to launch the jenkins from previous workspace. is there a way to restore the same old jobs?
I am starting jenkins like

> java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8083 &

But is there a way to provide workspace from commandline?

Answer (score 0):

Workspace is a specific term related to jobs in Jenkins. I think you are looking for JENKINS_HOME.  Set the environment variable to the path to the directory that has all your jenkins config and jobs before you start Jenkins.